# Flutter выводит ошибку: nosuchmethoderror the method [] was called on null, как решить?

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk, flutter, dart

Есть такой код (где встречается `[]`):

```
  Future<List<User>> getRequest() async {
    String url = "https://site.ru/list";
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    var responseData = json.decode(response.body);
    List<User> users = [];
    for (var singleUser in responseData) {
      User user = User(
          username: singleUser["username"],
          password: singleUser["password"]);
      users.add(user);
    }
    return users;
  }
```

Flutter выводит ошибку: nosuchmethoderror the method [] was called on null, как решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот один из вариантов (проверка `singleUser` на `null` до того, как он преобразуется в `User`:

```
  Future<List<User>> getRequest() async {
    String url = "https://site.ru/list";
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    var responseData = json.decode(response.body);
    List<User> users = [];
    for (var singleUser in responseData) {
      if (singleUser != null) {
        User user = User(
          username: singleUser["username"],
          password: singleUser["password"],
        );
        users.add(user);
      }
    }
    return users;
  }
```